# Show only items in ng-repeat, when they are not in an other ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a AngularJS problem and don't know how to deal with it. I have 2 ng-repeat lists, which contain the same objects.

The first list is showing "all" items. The second one should contain only some specific items. So now, i would filter the first list by the second one, to show the items only in one list.

So now, is there an option to filter List 1 by List 2?? The items are objects like

{'id':1, 'name':'test', 'alias':'test'}

Is there a simple way to realize this filter?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to remove the item from the first list when you add it to the second one (assuming that's what you want to achieve, which is not clear)?

Comment: Yeah i already did that. But i want to filter the data already when i get it from the database. There is a path where i get the list of all items (in JSON) and a path where i get the items that are already selected.